# How to set a placeholder in drupal 7 on a login form

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms, drupal-7

I need to set a placeholder for a horizontal login form in Drupal 7. This text needs to disappear when clicked on. They will just say 'username' and 'password'. Here is the code for the form as of now. Thanks!

```
function horizontal_login_block($form) {
$form['#action'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
$form['#id'] = 'horizontal-login-block';
$form['#validate'] = user_login_default_validators();
$form['#submit'][] = 'user_login_submit';
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="loginbar">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['name'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#prefix' => '<div class="usericon">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
 '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
 '#default_value' => t('Username'),
 '#id' => 'userbar',
 '#size' => 15,
 '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how to do it in HTML5, using placeholder HTML attribute. However, it's not working in any Internet Explorer version.

```
    function horizontal_login_block($form) {
    $form['#action'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
    $form['#id'] = 'horizontal-login-block';
    $form['#validate'] = user_login_default_validators();
    $form['#submit'][] = 'user_login_submit';
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="loginbar">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['name'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#prefix' => '<div class="usericon">',
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
     '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
/* Don't set default values. HTML5
     '#default_value' => t('Username'), */
     '#id' => 'userbar',
     '#size' => 15,
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Username'))
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! any idea of a fix for IE on this?

Comment: For older browsers may http://drupal.org/project/jquery_placeholder be possibly useful.

Answer (score 22):

Another simple way is to add this function to your themes *template.php*:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id )
{
    if (in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block')))
    {
        $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Username' );
        $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Password' );
    }
}
```

This will add HTML5 placeholders to the Username und Password fields in both login forms.

Dont forget to change the beginning of the functions name!

Have fun!

Comment: and to add a placeholder for search, add the following within the function: if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') { $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search...'); }

Comment: an improvement for this code to hide the labels `$form['name']['#title_display'] = "invisible"; $form['pass']['#title_display'] = "invisible";`

Comment: Further improvement: instead of explicitly writing the placeholder text, re-use the label: `$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $form['name']['#title'];` `$form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $form['pass']['#title'];`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this module https://www.drupal.org/project/form_placeholder implements an HTML 5 placeholder and for older browsers older browsers not "supporting HTML5 placeholder attribute uses jQuery Placeholder plugin by Mathias Bynens".