# How to add placeholders in customized module?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal, currently i am creating a new module for forms. inside of the module i added the code as follows .

```
$form['first name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    );
```

in this case i wanted to use place holders for text fields.
So how can i do ?

Comment: I think this question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830736/how-to-set-a-placeholder-in-drupal-7-on-a-login-form

Comment: I have tried , it is working fine when i put it for only one text field, but when i put place holder for two text fields, i does not show the page, instead it simply displays blank page.

Comment: If you get a blank page in Drupal, you probably need to turn on error reporting to see what is going on: https://www.drupal.org/node/158043

Answer (score 0):

Give them in #attributes like below

'#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('placeholder text goes here'))